# How do you override a spring bean defined in xml using Annotations?

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

I have an existing bean `overrideBean` defined in `spring.xml` which I would like to override using annotations.  I have tried the following to override the bean:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"/spring.xml"})
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DdwMain.class);

        Object o = context.getBean("overrideBean");
        // o should be null but it is not
    }

    @Bean(name="overrideBean")
    public OverrideBean overrideBean() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Using the above code the bean from the `spring.xml` config is always instantiated and returned by the `context.getBean` call.

The bean can be overridden by including another XML config file in the `@ImportResource` however I would prefer to find a solution using annotations would be cleaner.

Comment: Why is your `Main` class the Spring `@Configuration` class? What happens if you instantiate the Spring context using a different `@Configuration` class`?

Comment: `ImportResource` is done only after all bean definitions from the `@Configuration` class are read. So the definition replacement is done in the opposite way than you are expecting. I can imagine that you can find related feature request in Spring Jira.

Comment: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7341

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually xml-registered beans have precedence. So you can override annotated beans with xml-configured ones but you are trying to do it the other way around. Can you not use a different bean name and select it among multiple candidates by using the **@Qualifier** annotation?

Most of the time combining xml with autoscanning is error-prone.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. I was going to write the same here :)

Comment: **@Qualifer** doesn't help.  Overriding a bean prevents the first bean from existing.  The @Qualifier just helps with autowiring.  The xml and auto scanning comment is more correct.

Comment: Thats right. It was just an idea because I thought you might have some beans you don't have control over coming from some library... so you can override behaviour and then by the means of the @Qualifier annotation choose your user-defined bean...

Comment: @TodorKolev I think the answer for now is don't do it.

Comment: > Most of the time combining xml with autoscanning is error-prone.

Agree

Answer (score 5):

I'm working in an older app (spring 3.1.1) that's configured via xml, but I needed to shuffle some config around for testing without deviating too far from the production config. My approach is to use a BeanPostProcessor.

```
package myapp.test;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer;

import myapp.spring.config.ComplexSpringConfiguration;

/**
 * Closely resembles production configuration for testing
 * @author jim
 */
@Configuration
@ImportResource("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml")
@Import(ComplexSpringConfiguration.class)
public class TestConfig {
    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    static {
        System.setProperty("env.test", "system");
    }

    //Override templateLoaderPath with something amenable to testing
    @Bean
    public BeanPostProcessor beanPostProcessor(){
        return new BeanPostProcessor(){
            @Override
            public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException  {
                //Override templateLoaderPath with something amenable to testing
                if(beanName.equals("freemarkerConfig")) {
                    logger.debug("overriding bean with name:" + beanName);
                    FreeMarkerConfigurer fc = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
                    fc.setTemplateLoaderPath("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/freemarker");
                    bean = fc;
                }
                return bean;
            }

            @Override
            public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
                return bean;
           }  
       };
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContext servletContext(){
        MockServletContext mockContext = new MockServletContext();
        mockContext.setContextPath("/myapp");
        return mockContext;
    }
}
```